# SyntaxError: unterminated string literal (Underscore templates)

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, underscore.js-templating

I am using Underscore templates and am passing values to my template as below;

```
{
    title:  self.options.title,
    subtitle:   self.options.subtitle,
    fieldVal:   self.options.fieldVal,
    fieldAttr: self.options.fieldAttr
}
```

And I am using the same inside my html template as below;

```
<textarea name="<%= fieldAttr.fieldName %>" id="<%= fieldAttr.fieldName %>" <%= fieldAttr.readonly == false ? 'disabled' : '' %> <%= fieldAttr.dataModelId != undefined ? "data-model-id='" + fieldAttr.dataModelId + '" : "" %> ><%= fieldVal %></textarea>
```

I am getting error
**SyntaxError: unterminated string literal**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an open double quote. You have this:

```
..."data-model-id='" + fieldAttr.dataModelId + '"
```

Which should be this:

```
..."data-model-id='" + fieldAttr.dataModelId + "'"
```

Comment: Thx...But i am now getting ReferenceError: invalid assignment left-hand side ....for ? data-model-id=' + fieldAttr.dataModelId + ' : '' ))==...

Comment: Just to clarify...my requirement is i want to set data-model-id as the attribute of textarea only if it has some value (otherwise skip it)

Comment: Have you removed the quotes around `data-model-id`?